# Killing old process with BroadcastSystemMessage

Tags: c++, windows-messages

I have an application (native C++, Windows), that cannot be run simultaneously on one machine. The behavior that I want to implement is this: on the attempt to run second instance of the application the first one stops running.

To do so I want to use WinApi function BroadcastSystemMessage() something like an example below.

When the application start it sends:

```
BroadcastSystemMessage(BSF_POSTMESSAGE, &dwRecepients, 0x666, 0, 0);
```

But, when I run my application in debug mode it doesn't hit

```
case 0x666:
    int iClose = 0 + 1;
break;
```

when I start another instance. The other messages are nandled correctly (WM_KEYDOWN, WM_ACTIVATE and others).

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: This is called Single instance application, there a a lot of samples how to do this, usually with named mutex. For example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243953

Comment: Ok, but most of those examples sipmply doesn't allow to run another instance. In my case — I need to kill the old one. There is a possibility that first one is stuck in running processes, so, it is preferable killing the old one rather than not allowing new one to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to broadcast a custom message you need to create an id for it with the [RegisterWindowMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, for example:

```
UINT msg666 = RegisterWindowMessage(L"custom_devil_message");
```

and use it both in the sending and receiving code:

```
// sending code
BroadcastSystemMessage(BSF_POSTMESSAGE, &dwRecepients, msg666, 0, 0);

// receiving code
case msg666:
    int iClose = 0 + 1;
break;
```

Remember that messages do not work for console applications.

Answer (score 0):

The solution began to work after I changed the type of the message to `WM_APPCOMMAND + 10`. Anyway, it didn't help, because BroadcastSystemMessage() doesn't broadcast messages to tabs in a browser, which is my case. Also, I couldn't find the range of message types that are allowed to be sent with BroadcastSystemMessage().